# Apache Archiva with ssl proxy

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, maven

I am quite a newbie in the field of server configuration. 
At work we want to setup a Maven repository with Apache Archiva, basically we want a place in which store the Maven projects we create. 
I am able to run Archiva on localhost and to access it via http. 
To be able to access to the repository via SSL, we wanted to configure Apache to act as a SSL proxy, I followed many guides (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871001/how-to-setup-apache-archiva-to-use-https-instead-of-http) on how to do that but the answer I get when I try to connect via https is

> An error occurred during a connection to server_ip:8080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

My Virtual Host configuration looks like this:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName server_ip
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy http://localhost:8080>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path_to_cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_to_key
    ProxyPass /http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: You (and maybe the tutorial you read) misspelled `ProxyPassReverse`.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga my fault, I was copying this part from another machine and I made a spelling mistake, I'll edit it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the missing space in the line "ProxyPass /http://localhost:8080/" which I presume to be a copy/paste error (otherwise you server would not start), you only need "SSLProxyEngine On" when proxying *to* https, but you are pryxing to http, so you do not need this. Remove this directive and re-try, it should work.

Also you do not need the <Proxy http://localhost:8080 > block. These sorts of blocks are (almost) exclusively for configuring forward proxies, whereas you have a reverse proxy. They are very common across various 'guides' out on the internet, but they are not needed.